# How to express percentage with decimal in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

```
SELECT RecruitmentSource,  COUNT(RecruitmentSource) AS NumberOfHired, COUNT(RecruitmentSource)/SUM(COUNT(RecruitmentSource)) OVER () AS PercentageHired
FROM HRDataset_v14$
GROUP BY RecruitmentSource
```

Percentage Hired that I expect as below link

[image: The result from SQL Server]

FYI, Total Number of Hired is 311 so I expect the number would be like

```
1. 0.0739
2. 0.0932
3. 0.0997
.
.
.
9. 0.0418
```

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does integer division.  I usually just multiply by `1.0` to avoid this:

```
SELECT RecruitmentSource,  COUNT(RecruitmentSource) AS NumberOfHired, 
       COUNT(RecruitmentSource) * 1.0/SUM(COUNT(RecruitmentSource)) OVER () AS PercentageHired
FROM HRDataset_v14$
GROUP BY RecruitmentSource
```